# Tracking Tag Elements

Tags: google-analytics

I have a set of tags on all of my article pages which I'd like to track. Ideally I want to see how many page visitors etc each tag gets. I want to be able to track pages that are tagged with `beer` and `cheese` and any other tags that it may find within the tag-group class.

```
<div class="tag-group"> 
  <p> 
   <a href="/tag/beer">beer</a> 
  </p> 

  <p>
    <a href="/tag/cheese">cheese</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is this possible with Google Analytics? And if so, how? I've tried pokeing around the interface but I haven't been able to find a way to setup some sort of specific tracking targetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a perfect way to do this because you cant store multiple layer on Google Analytics, so in almost all the cases you need to store all the tags in a single array. (You can unse a custom dimention isBeer for example, but this can be not the proper way)

But this 2 options might help you on this

**Content grouping** : this allows you to group the content by writer, editor, tags, etc. But in this case you have to manage to see how you group the content. i don't see much future in this way but here is an option
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en

**Use Custom Dimentions**:  This is the easiest one, you can add all the tags in a single string inside the custom dimention, and them look for it on the plataform segmenting or using it as a second dimention (on the report ). 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en
the code on the pageview need to be modified to add this information:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Level 1');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is more and less an option for you?